# SQL Server : sending table ColumnName as Dynamic sql Argument

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I have to write a procedure where I have to pass column name as a passing argument. The column name will be created from a select statement using some case conditions. The problem is that when I put the dynamically generated column name in the select statement like this

```
Select @columnName 
from TableName
```

It does not pull the data of the column from the table. Here is the full code

```
declare @term as varchar(10) ='201610'
declare @ColumnName CHAR(10)
declare @Source nvarchar (4000)

set @Source = N'

declare @ColumnName VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @replacement TABLE (ratio varchar(50), CCode varchar(10), t1 float, t2 float, t3 float, t4 float, t5 float)

insert into @replacement

select      case    when Level=''A'' then ''0''
                    when Level=''B'' then ''1''
                    when Level in (''C'', ''D'') then ''2''    
            end as ratio, 
            new.CCode, 
            1.0*sum(new.t1)/sum(deg.t1) as t1,
            1.0*sum(new.t2)/sum(deg.t2) as t2,
            1.0*sum(new.t3)/sum(deg.t3) as t3,
            1.0*sum(new.t4)/sum(deg.t4) as t4,
            1.0*sum(new.t5)/sum(deg.t5) as t5
from
            (
                select  level, 
                        CCode, 
                        sum(case when (Term/100)='+ @Term +'/100-4 then val end) as t1,
                        sum(case when (Term/100)='+ @Term +'/100-3 then val end) as t2,
                        sum(case when (Term/100)='+ @Term +'/100-2 then val end) as t3,
                        sum(case when (Term/100)='+ @Term +'/100-1 then val end) as t4,
                        sum(case when (Term/100)='+ @Term +'/100 then val end) as t5
                from    new
                group by level, CCode
            )new
left join
            (
                select  levelCode, CCode, 
                        sum(case when (Term/100)='+ @Term +'/100-4 then val end) as t1,
                        sum(case when (Term/100)='+ @Term +'/100-3 then val end) as t2,
                        sum(case when (Term/100)='+ @Term +'/100-2 then val end) as t3,
                        sum(case when (Term/100)='+ @Term +'/100-1 then val end) as t4,
                        sum(case when (Term/100)='+ @Term +'/100 then val end) as t5
                from    deg
                group by levelCode, CCode
            )deg
            on new.level=deg.levelCode and new.CCode=deg.CCode

group by 
            case    when Level=''A'' then ''0''
                    when Level=''B'' then ''1''
                    when Level in (''C'', ''D'') then ''2''    
            end, 
            new.CCode


set @ColumnName= (Select top 1 Column1 from 
(Select Case when t5 is not null then ''t5''
            when t5 is null and t4 is not null then ''t4''
            when t5 is null and t4 is null and t3 is not null then ''t3''
            when t5 is null and t4 is null and t3 is null and t2 is not null then ''t2''
            end as Column1 
from @replacement
)tempt  
where column1 is not null)
--Select @ColumnName

Select t4 from @replacement
Select @ColumnName from @replacement
'   

EXEC(@Source)
```

For the select statement `Select t4 from @replacement` it prints the column data. But for the statement `Select @ColumnName from @replacement` it just prints the column name stored in @ColumnName.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with the code? Is there any other way to get the data of the column whose name is dynamically pulled like the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line with @ColumnName to this: `Select ' + @ColumnName + ' from @replacement`.  Otherwise the value of @ColumnName is not being evaluated.

Comment: I tried. But It does not print any result. There is only one message in the result window:     Command(s) completed successfully.     No table is printed